# Should I see flags for a question that has been closed 5 hours ago?

Tags: support, flags

When looking at the flag queue on Stack Overflow, I noticed that one of the flags was for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916836/website-with-java-activities-for-begginers, which was closed 5 hours ago; clearly the question was flagged before it was closed.

> [image: screenshot]

Should I see the flag in the flag queue? The question has been already closed and, not being a 20K user, I cannot vote to delete it.

Since the moment it has been closed, the question was not edited from the OP. If that happened, the question would appear in the re-opening review queue; there would not be any reason for still showing it in the flag queue.

Comment: When the text is grayed out like that it means it was already dismissed and there's a new flag on it (in cases like this, usually after it was closed). If you can't see it it may be a mod-only flag.